# how to determine whether a field type is a List (or any other type of collections) using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I have something like:

```
Field [] fields = claz.getDeclaredFields();
 for(Field f : fields){
    f.setAccessible(true);
    if(f.getType().equals(List.class)){
        Method m = f.getType().getMethod("size");
        int length = (Integer)m.invoke(f.get(node));
        System.out.println("length "+ length);
        }
}
```

it does work, but I'm wondering to know if there is any other good approaches, like something that will work for all other collections (TreeSet, HashSet, etc...), or the only way is that, I have to check for each type like what I already have?

thanks

Comment: Do you have to use reflection? Why not just use `if (node instanceof Collection) length = ((Collection)node).size()`?

Comment: @eran You are on to something, but OP would need `if (f.get(node) instanceof Collection)`, so reflection would still be used to access the field.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, you're right, I overlooked that fact that `node` is the object whose fields are checked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `Field` object you could retrieve the Type and pass it as parameter for the method `isAssignableFrom` of `Collection.class`.

Like:

```
...
boolean isCollection = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())
...
```

From documentation the method `isAssignableFrom`:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It
>   returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object
>   represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified
>   Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns
>   false.

The same should be done with `Map`:

```
boolean isMap = Map.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered checking if the type implements the Map or Collection interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())`  will work for all collection types - all implementations of lists and sets.

`Maps` would have to be checked separately however, as they do not implement the `Collection` interface.